# Chrome failed to start: crashed. error message appeared while running test cases using Docker

Tags: selenium-webdriver

(The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed) error message appeared while running UI test cases using selenium , python and chrome driver)

I am attempting to run the test cases using Selenium Python via Docker and am encountering several difficulties.

Here is tech stalk information,

Selenium: 4.11.2

Python version: 3.10

Chrome Driver: 116.0.5845.96

Chrome Binary: 116.0.5845.96

Docker File:

```
RUN pip install logging-formatter-anticrlf

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9
# Chrome dependency
WORKDIR /usr/bin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatspi2.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libdrm2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libgtk-4-1 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libwayland-client0 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libxrandr2 \
    xdg-utils \
    libu2f-udev \
    libvulkan1 \
    software-properties-common \
    unzip \
    curl \
    xvfb
 # Chrome instalation
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_116.0.5845.96-1_amd64.deb
RUN apt --fix-broken install

RUN apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_116.0.5845.96-1_amd64.deb -y

RUN echo "Chrome: " && google-chrome --version


WORKDIR /module

COPY . .
COPY setup.py setup.py
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
COPY README.md README.md


RUN pip install webdriver-manager==4.0.0
RUN pip install selenium==4.11.2
RUN pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
RUN pip install selenium --user
RUN pip install py3chrome
RUN wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip

RUN mv chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod 777 /usr/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod 777 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome


RUN pytest -k test_case
```

Test case

```
def test_case():
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService, Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 #s = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
 chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--privileged')

 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
 chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')# overcome limited resource problems
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
 chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
 chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")
 chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this

 chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
     "prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1}
 )
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

 driver.get(“www.google.com”)
```

When I run the test case in local it is working fine without any issues

[Local run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhkBX.png)

But same test case is failing when running in the docker:

[Docker run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmauU.png)

I also tried the following methods:
1. Avoid pre-installation of driver and binary; instead, let Selenium Manager handle the installation; the installation took place in the root directory and still produced the same issue.
2. Downloaded the Chrome drivers into a folder and entered the executable path in service (same issue as before)

I experimented with different options and capabilities, as well as lowering the selenium and driver versions.
Is there anything I'm missing in the docker file to support the chrome binary file? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?